# Pygame Button Function

Tags: python, pygame

I have set up a button function but was wondering how to put an image on the button instead of text.
In the class the attribute text='' allows text to be put on the button but was wondering how to chnage that to allow an image instead

```
class button():
    def __init__(self,color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
       self.color = color
       self.x = x
       self.y= y
       self.width = width
       self.height = height
       self.text = text

    def draw(self,win,outline=None):
        if outline:
           pygame.draw.rect(win , outline , (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
        
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color , (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
           font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans',60)
           text = font.render(self.text, 1 , (0,0,0))
           win.blit(text, (self.x +(self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - 
text.get_height()/2)))

    def isOver(self, pos ):
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and  pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `self.image` into the `__init_` function as:

```
self.image = pygame.image.load('image.png') # Make that the image is in the same folder as your python file
```

and at your function, simply blit `self.image` instead of `text`:

```
win.blit(self.image, (self.x +(self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - text.get_height()/2)))
```

All together:

```
class button():
    def __init__(self,color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
       self.color = color
       self.x = x
       self.y= y
       self.width = width
       self.height = height
       self.text = text
       self.image = pygame.image.load('image.png')

    def draw(self,win,outline=None):
        if outline:
           pygame.draw.rect(win , outline , (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
        
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color , (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
           font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans',60)
           text = font.render(self.text, 1 , (0,0,0))
           win.blit(self.image, (self.x +(self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - text.get_height()/2)))

    def isOver(self, pos ):
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and  pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False
```

Comment: Thanks Works perfectly ! However just wondering where i can move the image within the box as it doesn't quite line up

Comment: @Mace You can tweak it through the part: `(self.x +(self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - text.get_height()/2))`